# How do I prove that $(c,\infty]$ is open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: general-topology

$\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a topological space, but not a metric space, so I'm not sure if it is true.

Let $U$ be an open set in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $\infty\in U$.

Then, how do I that prove there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(c,\infty] \subset U$ and such that $(c,\infty]$ is an open set?

Comment: What is the definition of the topology on $\overline{\mathbb R}$?  (There is a standard topology, but knowing your precise definition makes it easier to answer your question, and your close examination of the definition may also lead you to answer your own question.)

Comment: @Jonas To be honest, i'm not sure which topology it should be for $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Would you tell me what is the standard topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$? Neighborhoods?

Comment: Standard topology is all the usual open sets, and then a set containing $\infty$ is open if and only if its complement is a compact set in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ do you mean $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ or $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ - \infty , + \infty \}$, or something else?

Comment: @Arthur I meant $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty,-\infty\}$. I think i got the answer. "$U$ is open iff $\forall x\in U, [x\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon>0 B(x,\epsilon)\subset U]\bigvee [x=\infty \Rightarrow \exists c\in \mathbb{R} (c,\infty]\subset U] \bigvee [x=-\infty \Rightarrow \exists c\in \mathbb{R} [-\infty,c)\subset U]$". Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, your characterisation of the open subsets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is correct.  (Or, at least, this is the natural way of defining the topology on this set.)